# No module named Selenium; requirement already satisfied

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Error in Terminal

[image: Error in Terminal]

Installation error

[image: Installation error]

I'm trying to run a simple test program to open a window using Selenium. Unfortunately, I keep receiving an error message saying no module named selenium. When I try to install it, it says that *requirement already satisfied*. At this point I'm confused on what to do.. any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you running Python 2 or 3? It's possible you're only installing Selenium on one version, and not the other. This is a pretty common problem.

Comment: please show the actual error msgs.  also display your PATH.  it might just not know where to look.

Comment: I am running Python 2 and I checked what versions I was running for each & both matched. Also, I am in my virtualenv

Comment: @ShpielMeister I edited my question and have included screenshots

Comment: it looks like your code is running in a VirtualEnvironment but Selenium got installed into your system's global python packages namespace. If possible try to backup/copy your code out of the virtualenvironment directory (`Scraping6`?) then delete and recreate the VirtualEnvironment, and replace the code. Then activate the VirtualEnvironment and try installing `selenium` in that fresh virtualenv. Might clear out any conflicts.

Comment: @Ty'TeonnaFranklin I don't really see the error **No module named Selenium** in your trace logs. Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue, and i fixed this way:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

instead of:

```
pip install selenium
```

hope it works for you too